# Vb net publish folder data size gets larger

Tags: vb.net, size, publish

Hi new to this q and a darabase but looking forward to the experience.

Vb net . Each time  I publish a project , it grows by around  1 or 2 mbytes.
Even if I just republish a unchanged project into a clean new folder it goes up by 2 meg!.
i can't understand why , or have found a way to stop this happening.
Using visual studio express 2013 ver 12.0 .31.101.00 update 4
Writing code in vb 2013.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved when the software publishes it does not at delete the old application files in the publish folder. Delete any old files and all is fixed.